# PHP array's definitions possibilities

Tags: php, arrays

If i have some variables like $val1, $val2, $val3, ...
and convert to arr

```
$arr = ['val1' => $val1, 'val2' => $val2, 'val3' => $val3,..];
```

is it possible to define a shortly this array like this?

```
$arr = a('val1', 'val2', 'val3', ..)
```

Comment: Ref: https://www.php.net/manual/function.compact.php ?

Answer (score 1):

If keys are not important, you may write

`$arr = [$val1, $val2, $val3];`

or

`$arr = array($val1, $val2, $val3);`

Comment: more compact than `[$val1, $val2, $val3]` ? what are you looking for ?

Comment: $a = 1; $b = 2; -- compact('a','b') is the same than array('a' => $a, 'b' => $b).